# Puppet modules and the self-contained design

Tags: puppet

From Puppet Best Practices:

> The Puppet Labs documentation describes modules as **self-contained** bundles of code and data.

Ok it's clear.

> A single module can easily manage a single application.

So, *puppetlabs-apache* manages Apache only, *puppetlabs-mysql* manages MySQL only.

.... So, my module *my_company-mediawiki* manages Mediawiki only (i suppose... with database and virtual host... because a module is self-contained bundles of code and data).

> Modules are most effective when the serve a single purpose, **limit dependencies**, and concern themselves only with managing system state relating to their named purpose.

But *my_company-mediawiki* needs to depend by:

- puppetlabs-mysql: to create database;
- puppetlabs-apache: to manage a virtual host.

And... from a rapid search I understand that many modules refer to other modules.

But...

> They provide complete functionality without creating dependencies on any other modules, and can be combined as needed to build different application stacks.

Ok, a good module is self-contained and has no dependencies.

So I have to necessarily use the pattern roles and profiles to accomplish these best practices? Or I'm confused...

Comment: There is a good question buried in here. Could you edit this into something more coherent?

Comment: Sure. Like? Could you give me some examples?

Answer (score 1):

The Puppet documentation's description of modules as self-contained is more aspirational than definitive.  Don't read too much into it, or into others' echoes of it. Modules are quite simply Puppet's next level of code organization above classes and defined types, incorporating also plug-ins and owned data.

Plenty of low-level modules indeed have no cross-module dependencies, but such dependencies inescapably arise when you start forming aggregations at a level between that and whole node configurations.  There is nothing inherently wrong with that.  The Roles & Profiles pattern is a good way to structure such aggregations, but it is not the only way, and in any case it does not avoid cross-module dependencies because role and profile classes, like any other, should themselves belong to modules.

Comment: Conveys well that there is so much opinion and misinterpretation in Puppet design best practices, while stressing the best end goal is reduced complexity.